# Node Prototypes and Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, prototype

How would I return the value of the asynchronous function within read() when I call log()? I know the code may not be 100% correct, but I'm hoping you get the idea. I Googled around but am still a little confused. Hoping someone can help me out.

```
function Whatever(directory) {
  this.source = 'someDir';
}

Whatever.prototype.read = function (dir) {
  dir = dir || this.source;

  recursive(dir, ['.*'], function (err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return files;
  });

};

Whatever.prototype.log = function() {

  console.log(this.read());

};
```

Comment: bad pattern to throw error like that, nowhere to catch it. Use promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a callback to the read function, the same way the recursive function does it, eg:

```
Whatever.prototype.read = function (dir, callback) {
    dir = dir || this.source;
    recursive(dir, ['.*'], callback);
};
```

Then you put your error check and usage inside your log function:

```
Whatever.prototype.log = function() {
    this.read(function(err, files){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        console.log(files);
    });
};
```

There are plenty of links online explaining callbacks in more details, which you should investigate. However, once you master those, I suggest reading about promises, as they are much better to deal with.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. That's exactly what I was looking for. I definitely have some reading to do.